# What does it mean that the variance is equal to covariance?

Tags: variance, covariance, unbiased-estimator

I am reading a paper that says that for forecast unbiasdness it is necessary to asusume that Cov(x,x̂)=Var(x̂), where x̂ is the estimate and x is the true value. How should I interpret this assumption, what is this assumption saying intuitively? Why is it important?

Here is the actual assumption taken from the paper:
[image]

Comment: $\text{var}(a)=\text{cov}(a,a)$, so presumably it's asking you to assume that your estimate is equal to the true value of the parameter.

Comment: @Stats How does that follow?  I can only conclude $\operatorname{Cov}(x,\hat x-x)=0.$

Comment: @whuber Do you mean $\text{Cov}(\hat{x},\hat{x}-x)=0$ ?

Comment: @Stats Yes: the omission of the first hat is a typo; thanks for catching that.

Comment: @StatsPlease i added a picture of the assumption to the question